# C# SQL command query produces "could not be bound" error

Tags: sql-server

My scenario is this: The Master table contains millions of records. The primary key is "Timestamp". Now I need to add data imported from .csv to a Datatable. Some of the rows in the Datatable may already contain specific timestamps, and those rows should not (rather cannot - due to primary key being Timestamp) be inserted into the Master table.

So I create a Temp table and sqlbulkcopy into it from the Datatable. Then I use the following command to insert new rows into the Master table from the Temp table. "new" being all those in the Temp table who's Timestamps do not yet exist in the Master table:

```
INSERT INTO Master
SELECT *
FROM Temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Timestamp FROM Temp WHERE Master.Timestamp = Temp.Timestamp)
```

and getting this exception:

> The multi-part identifier "Master.Timestamp" could not be bound.

I can't seem to figure out how to modify the INSERT statement to do what it needs to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could not be `found`, not `bound`. I'd bet the `Master` table doesn't contain a column named `Timestamp`. BTW using `Master` as a name is a bad idea because SQL Server already has a `master` database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The error message correctly says "bound", not "found", which is the message shown when an object is not found, curiously.

Comment: Bound was not a typo, yes bound... I changed the name to Master in the quoted example only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the logic backwards. Your subquery should select from master, not temp. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp as tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Master as mst 
    WHERE mst.Timestamp = tmp.Timestamp);
```